# Why do we have to check ker(T)=0 for isomorphism when I know that dim (V)=dim(W)?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Suppose I want to prove that $P_2$ is isomorphic to $R^3$. Why is it not sufficient to prove dim($P_2$)=dim($R^3$) and apply Thm part (b)? Why do I have to show that the ker($T$)=$0$?

Comment: No, you don't have to. It's enough to prove $\dim(P_2)=\dim(R^3)$ to prove it's isomorphic.

Comment: The textbook says it. I am not able to attach the screenshot in the comments.

Comment: Do you want to show that $P_2$ is isomorphic to $R^2$? Or do you want to show that some specific $T\colon P_2\to R^2$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @math It's essentially the same as the difference between the statements "the crime was witnessed" and "Joseph Schmoe witnessed the crime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between "two spaces are isomorphic" and "the linear transformation $T$ is an isomorphism between the two spaces".

If have two (finite dimensional) vector spaces $V$ and $W$, and you want to check that two are isomorphic, it's enough to compare dimensions. If you also have a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ ($V, W$ still finite dimensional), and you want to check that $T$ is an isomorphism, then you have to check that $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic (i.e. compare dimensions) and also that $T$ is injective (i.e. check the kernel).

The theorem you provided is all about the latter case, while it seems that your actual problem (comparing $P_2$ to $\Bbb R^2$) is about the former.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove $\ker(T) = \{0\}$ or $\text{im}(T) = W$, and then ($V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional spaces with the same dimension) the other is automatically true.

Comment: why can't I just use theorem part (b) and show that dimensions are the same and hence they are isomorphic?

Comment: If you just want to prove they are isomorphic (without specifying a particular isomorphism $T$), then you just need to show the dimensions are the same.
I thought you wanted to prove that a particular $T$ is an isomorphism.